# 'prop_menu_enum' dropdown gives random results, when passing generated List to the scene enum

Tags: python, add-on, properties

Blender 2.83.1 LTS under Windows 10.

I'm trying to make a Generalised preset tool, which reads in Json files and ultimately writes (to learn a bit more).

I get odd results in my 'prop_menu_enum' when I generate a list (from a Json file). However everything is reported correct elsewhere. In the Info window correct names, in the Scene properties dropdown correct names also. Just wrong in my dropdown, looks like it's reading info in Json file even though I'm passing it a list which doesn't contain said data.

I've tested with adding the same data into a typed list (not gernerate) and this works OK. When printed both lists look identical so I'm a bit stumped and at the edge of my expereince.

I'll post my code and Json file, any help or advice appreciated.

```
import bpy
import json
import os.path


def selected_preset_file(self, context):
    presetPath = bpy.path.abspath(bpy.context.scene.preset_path)
    return presetPath


def update_presets_enum(self, context):
    print("\n=== READING JSON FILE ====")
    filePath = selected_preset_file(self, context)

    with open(filePath) as file:  # extract preset keys, from the file into a new list.
        data = json.load(file)
        presets = []
        for key in data:
            presets.append(key)

    enum_items = []  # update the enum presets list
    n = 1
    for presetName in presets:
        listItem = (presetName, presetName, '', n)
        enum_items.append(listItem)
        n += 1
    print("Created list is: %s" % (presets))
    print("Passed enum is: %s" % (enum_items))

    enum_list = (enum_items)
    # enum_list = [('Game_UI_icons', 'Game_UI_icons', '', 1), ('Game_promo', 'Game_promo', '', 2), ('Game_dev', 'Game_dev', '', 3)]
    return enum_list
    # return enum_items


def write_json(self, context, data, filePath):
    with open(filePath, "w") as file:
        json.dump(data, file, indent=4)


class OBJECT_OT_write_to_json(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Testing how to write data to a json file"""
    bl_idname = "object.write_to_json"
    bl_label = "Write to json file"

    def execute(self, context):
        print("hello")
        return{'FINISHED'}

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.area.type == 'VIEW_3D'


class VIEW_3D_PT_writeFile(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "Write File"
    bl_label = "Write to Json File"
    # bl_context = "object"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        col = layout.column()
        col.operator('object.write_to_json')
        col.prop(context.scene, 'preset_path')
        col.prop_menu_enum(context.scene, 'render_presets_enum', text='Select render preset')


regClasses = [OBJECT_OT_write_to_json,
              VIEW_3D_PT_writeFile,
              ]


def register():
    bpy.types.Scene.render_presets_enum = bpy.props.EnumProperty(items=update_presets_enum)
    bpy.types.Scene.preset_path = bpy.props.StringProperty(
        name='',
        subtype='FILE_PATH',
        default='/notset',
        description='Select a presets file',
    )
    for c in regClasses:
        bpy.utils.register_class(c)


def unregister():
    del bpy.types.Scene.render_presets_enum
    del bpy.types.Scene.preset_path
    for c in regClasses:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(c)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

and the Json file:

```
    {
    "Game_UI_icons": [
        {
            "Path": "D:/bl_test/",
            "Type": "PNG",
            "ResX": "256",
            "ResY": "256",
            "Start": "0",
            "End": "0"
        }
    ],
    
    "Game_promo": [
        {
            "Path": "D:/bl_test/",
            "Type": "PNG",
            "ResX": "1920",
            "ResY": "1080",
            "Start": "0",
            "End": "0"
        }
    ],

    "Game_dev": [
        {
            "Path": "D:/bl_test/",
            "Type": "PNG",
            "ResX": "256",
            "ResY": "256",
            "Start": "0",
            "End": "0"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: If using the fourth item (number) in an enum https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.EnumProperty generally for use as a ENUM_FLAG (multi select) suggest using powers of 2 eg `2 ** i` so they can be logically or'd.

Comment: thanks, I don't need that for this use case so I've removed the fourth item and just use the 3 mandatory tuples as per the docs. 
Hasn't changed the outcome of my dropdown mind.

Comment: Hmm. I seem to be able to get the list drawn correctly if I access the enum in a different way. 
Changing: `col.prop_menu_enum(context.scene, 'render_presets_enum', text='Select render preset')`
To: `col.prop(context.scene, 'render_presets_enum', text='')`
However I still don't know why the first attempt was giving odd results.

Comment: Been my experience that dynamic enums can get slow if always in UI and updating constantly. Consider a buffer list, repopulating when file is touched, or making enum an operator property.

Comment: Thanks again, I think I understand how I'd do the second method, I'll also look into how to do a buffer list. that might be more suitable for this?

Comment: simply some global list to repopulate from file when required... eg after writing to it.   Populate dynamic enum items using global  list.  As an example was using a dynamic enum to display vim text editor server names from a shell command worked Ok,  but blends left open overnight (or some time)  would become sluggish.

Comment: your comment to change prop_menu_enum to prop saved my life @MalReed